# How to make CKEditor4 work with the plugin files pre-loaded?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm looking into making CKEditor4 work with as many files pre-loaded as possible. For instance CKEditor loads the `styles.js` file on its own, it loads the plugin's css files and some more.

As a start, I tried to pre-load the plugin css files by adding them as `link` elements, just as CKEditor4 does in code. Then I disabled the css loading code in `ckeditor.js` like so: (I added the log call and the early return, other lines are unchanged.)

```
appendStyleSheet: function( cssFileUrl ) {
    console.log("want css: " + cssFileUrl);
    if (true) return; // MARK: all styles are already loaded
    if ( this.$.createStyleSheet )
        this.$.createStyleSheet( cssFileUrl );
    else {
        var link = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( 'link' );
        link.setAttributes( {
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            type: 'text/css',
            href: cssFileUrl
        } );

        this.getHead().append( link );
    }
},
```

This does not work. The editor does not show up.

Alternatively I commented out the `href` entry in the `setAttributes` call. This also does not work.

Does someone know why it does not work?

(EDIT:) I'm using the latest Chrome in Windows 7.

---

(I added the css files to my static test page like so - these are the ones, CKEditor loads by calling the `appendStyleSheet` function in that order:)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ext/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="ext/ckeditor/plugins/tableselection/styles/tableselection.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ext/ckeditor/plugins/balloontoolbar/skins/default.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ext/ckeditor/plugins/balloontoolbar/skins/moono-lisa/balloontoolbar.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ext/ckeditor/plugins/balloonpanel/skins/moono-lisa/balloonpanel.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ext/ckeditor/plugins/copyformatting/styles/copyformatting.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just a small tip, that might help you.

Try to remove this and see if it helps

```
CKEDITOR.document.appendStyleText( '.cke{visibility:hidden;}' );
```

Comment: I actually found this in the meantime. Anyway - thanks for the hint. I'm accepting this as the answer, since it is the main issue for my question.